# Is it possible to set an input element height to 0?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to change the height of an input element from 40px to 0px in hopes of making it disappear.

This effect works for images and looks decent but appears not to work for input elements.

However for input, it does not make it to 0px and disappear.

I would like to use CSS transitions to make an input slowly disappear.  Is this possible?

Here is a fiddle of what an input looks like with height: 0px.

https://jsfiddle.net/01geLwh7/

```css
.search_bar_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}

#search_bar_input_show {
  height: 40px;
}

#search_bar_input_hide {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input class="search_bar_input" id="search_bar_input_hide" name="search" type="text" placeholder=" Search" />
```

Comment: `#search_bar_input_show` isn't used anywhere

Comment: @Shahriar which does not matter for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reduce the padding and border of the input too:

```css
.search_bar_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}

#search_bar_input_show {
  height: 40px;
}

#search_bar_input_hide {
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input class="search_bar_input" id="search_bar_input_hide" name="search" type="text" placeholder=" Search" />
```

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot, however, I can not transition my border because it is too small, it goes from 1px to 0px.  Oddly changing the box-sizing did not help.

Comment: @howard you can transition the [`border-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) to become transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `transform: scale()` in these cases, mostly because it actually works. Second, `scale` multiplies the size so you don't need to change `height` multiple times if needed.

<s>Also, you [had] a typo in your HTML: `className` should be `class`.</s> (If you are using React then you're fine; thanks tacoshy).

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".search_bar_input");
setInterval(() => {
  if (input.id === "search_bar_input_show") {
    input.id = "search_bar_input_hide";
  } else {
    input.id = "search_bar_input_show";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.search_bar_input{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#search_bar_input_show{
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
#search_bar_input_hide{
  transform: scale(1, 0);
}
```

```html
<input
  class="search_bar_input"
  id="search_bar_input_show"
  name="search"
  type="text"
  placeholder=" Search"
/>
```

Also, using `transform`, you can also change [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Comment: `className` is not necessarily wrong. `React` as example uses it. It was just corrected by me in order to make the code reproducible.

Comment: I'm not sure the relevance of scale().  I found that I had extra dimensions added by the default padding and the border I set to 1px.  Oddly, changing the box-size property did not help.  What is the relevance of scale().  I did not understand you explanation.

Comment: @howard Scale literally scales all sizing properties like you learned in Algebra. It _scales_ the element by multiplying by whatever factor. You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())

Comment: @tacoshy I did slash that part out in my edit; should I just delete that part altogether?

Comment: Personally I would remove. However as the OP not specifically mentioned React or flagged it as such, it could be a legitimate info. Also I'm not a moderator nor does the guidelines specifically adress such a situation.